# Do Costumes Affect Breast Physics?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I've noticed that some of the female characters have two widely different costumes available.  Do any of these different costumes have an impact on character breast-physics?  The most obvious example would be *Hilde* who wears a suit of armor in her default costume, but not in her secondary costume, which is an outfit reminiscent of the American civil war.

Do costumes affect the body physics of female characters (or males for that matter)?

Comment: ummm. interesting question. why bother asking it?

Comment: Why does anyone ask anything on this site?  I want the answer to it.

Comment: Touché good sir. I deserved that.

Comment: +1 mildly adult question but so is the game. I've always wondered that about many games that go over the top with breast physics (DoA for example). My guess is no.

Comment: I'd love to hear the reason for the downvotes and the close votes as "off topic", if nothing more than for the humor of it.

Comment: If it's not perceivable to you, you'd need to ask a dev.  If it is and you already know, or purposefully didn't look and then asked this, then it's not an actual problem you face.

Comment: quite a few of us see no reason to close the question as it is actually within the rules and guidelines for the site. Its however downvoted (by those who also did not want it closed) because it was not deemed a front-page worthy question, so to speak. (This question was discussed excessively in chat)

Comment: @MatthewRead I haven't played all of the female characters in all of the costumes yet, and may not for quite some time, as I'd need to devote substantial time to it.  I was hoping someone else would know.

Comment: @Resorath One could just as reasonably ask why this question was deemed worthy of 9 upvotes.

Comment: It's an okay question, it's just been asked in a really immature way. Feel free to roll back if you like, Gnome, but I think this will get you less downvotes.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It'll get him less upvotes too.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think this changes the question slightly though. It makes it more broad, and in which case I don't think the original question is addressed directly. I think it is a better question, but not the original if that makes sense.

Comment: I downvoted because I feel that anyone who actually cares about this does not care very much about gaming.

Comment: I have feeling that when the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) updates, we're going to have a new [most controversial post on this site](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) :)

Comment: I can't lie, I was rather sure this question was going to get shot-down like an overfed turkey. However, it seems to be thriving and for that I salute you sir! Clearly I have much more to learn about the workings of this site.

Comment: This is clearly an important issue that affects gameplay. I've lost 100% of the matches wherein my opponent had a case of the jigglies.

Comment: @Maxx :D +1 for awesome comment

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [Well you nailed that one, 2013 and still hasn't been beaten!](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site)

Answer (score 41):

Apparently [you're not the only one who wanted to know](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/630214-/62029643). A selected quote for you:

> certain clothing (usually "solid" things like armor, or the voodoo top) disables jiggle physics so that the boobs don't clip through it.

Comment: I'm assuming full armour is the only equipment where this is the case?  Figures.