# Is There Any Way To Get Around Effects of Character Warping in Creation Mode?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I just spent upwards of 20 minutes trying to place a flower on Leixia's shoulder in a custom costume.  The problem I ran into (and never really got around), is that Leixia's breast jiggle during her fighting stance doesn't appear to affect only her breasts: the character mesh of her neck and shoulders seems to be affected as well.

Basically, I wasn't able to successfully place a flower on the front of her shoulder in such a way that, during her battle animation, it didn't *disappear inside her shoulder*, and then reappear repeatedly as she bounces from side to side.

Is there any way to minimize the effects of character warping when creating custom costumes, short of equipping 'solid armor' to the character as outlined [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52802/do-costumes-affect-breast-physics)?  Some of these warping effects make it really difficult to avoid strange behaviour when placing accessories on custom characters.

Comment: Do people not actually *read* things before they vote any more? =[

Comment: Maybe people are appalled that you're complaining about the jiggle physics. What are you, some kind of breast hater?

Comment: You are spitting in the face of the developers. They made real to life jiggle physics for the users sake.

Comment: I have to admit, the comments on this so far are the best part. :D

Comment: I'm starting to see a trend in your questions here... Jiggling, and Breasts. So, I'm guessing your a real 'look into her eye's' kind of guy eh?

Comment: @Emerica Maybe it is because it is Friday... but I read sake as [saké](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sake). 4:30 can't come soon enough!

Comment: @Adanion Maybe if you have enough saké you wouldn't even notice the jiggle physics anymore.

Comment: @Emerica if you have enough sake you won't notice *anything* anymore :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only constraint on accessories is which part of the body they're attached to. They'll move relative to that part's origin. Perhaps you can try attaching it to a different part of her body? If you're starting at shoulder, try starting at chest or arm and moving it to shoulder. If you're starting at chest and moving to shoulder, try starting at upper arm instead, or vice versa.

Failing that, perhaps you can move it out front a bit, so when her shoulder becomes inconsistent, there'll be a buffer before it starts disappearing. Of course, this means the flower would technically be hanging in midair, but from most points of view it should be fairly unnoticeable. If you have an extra accessory slot, you could try offsetting/hiding the gap with another accessory.

EDIT: I remembered this question and decided to try it today. I anchored a flower to her shoulder, and it followed the anchor perfectly, but disappeared into her shoulder when I attached it to chest. If shoulder's not anchoring for you, can you list what settings you're attempting to use? Everything on the "adjust equipment" screen if you can.

Comment: Attaching to the 'collarbone' instead of 'chest' does appear to fix this.  I guess you just need to be careful to anchor accessories to  body parts that don't 'move' as much as others.  Thanks!